# How to run an http executable/task in node.js

Tags: node.js

In my cucumber, node.js code, when I am spawning an executable, for a normal executable on the Windows environment, I can run this fine:

```
var spawnSync = require('child_process').execSync;
    var result = spawnSync(somethingToRun, {
        stdio: 'ignore',
        timeout: 1100*1000
    });
```

However, when somethingToRun is an http link such as:

```
https://myhost.com:9000/tasks/runMe.exe
```

I'm getting:

```
Error: Command failed: https://myhost.com:9000/tasks/runMe.exe
```

Am I running this incorrectly?  I have powershell scripts that run these links fine.  Forgive if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find it.  Thanks for redirecting, or helping out!

Comment: Command must one that can be executed in an OS shell. Just like when you type to your Bash or zsh prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That powershell supports running programs from URLs is troubling. It opens one up to an attack that wouldn't so easily be possible.

But if you must you can implement by fetching the program from the URL with http(s?).get and then running it.

But beware. I did warn you. This is a bad design.

Comment: Thanks, these are all internal links,but I hear ya.

Comment: It could be made safer if you only accept a whitelist of domains and their associated certificates.